# Suitescript scheduled search returning some field values and not others

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a scripted search that works on some fields and not others and cannot work out why it is. It doesn't work for any fields relating to the dollar amount of the sales order which is the main reason we need this search! This is my code which works for all fields except amount which returns a blank column in the csv that is exported. Have also tried with customer fields and it works fine. API 2.0

```
  var salesorderSearchObj = search.create({
      type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
      filters: [
        ["type", search.Operator.ANYOF, "SalesOrd"],
        "AND",
        ["mainline", search.Operator.IS, "T"]
      ],
      columns: [
        search.createColumn({ name: "trandate", label: "Date" }),
        search.createColumn({ name: "amount", label: "Amount" }),
        search.createColumn({ name: "tranid", label: "Document Number" }),
        search.createColumn({ name: "entity", label: "Name" })
      ]
    });

    var yourCSVData = "Date,Amount,Document Number,Name\n";


    salesorderSearchObj.run().each(function (result) {
      yourCSVData += [
        result.getValue({ name: "trandate" }),
        result.getText({ name: "amount" }),
        result.getValue({ name: "tranid" }),
        result.getText({ name: "entity" })
      ].join(",") + "\n";

      return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Amount field you need to use `result.getValue('amount')` rather than `result.getText('amount')`.

More generally: only use `getText()` when you need to return the text value of a SELECT field (where using `getValue()` would return an internal ID).  Example: the Customer (or "entity") field in the example above would return a numerical internal ID (eg: 12345) if you use `getValue()` and the textual customer name (eg: ACME International) when you use `getText()`.  When called on other field types, `getText()` will return `null`.